How to add space to Navbar to display an additional view?
Imagine everything above the black bar is the navbar and if you scroll down that will always stay on top. Problem is I'm unable to do this since I have my toolbar.

/// Temporary search bar, make this functional later
ToolbarItem(placement: .principal){
    HStack{
        Image(systemName:"magnifyingglass")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
          .foregroundStyle(.shuttleGray)
          .padding(.leading, 5)
          
        
        Text("Search messages")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.shuttleGray)
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName:"slider.horizontal.3")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
          .foregroundStyle(.shuttleGray)
     
        
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .padding(8)
    .background(.concrete)
    .cornerRadius(10)
    
}

Which already takes up all the space, adding in a VStack or something inside the principal tool bar item seems like a bad way to do this and that also restricts the width of Divider rectangles I have. Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this?
This is also my code for the focused & other buttons + dividers
VStack{
    /// Tab view for both Focused & Other tabs
    /// Can see later if worth switching to Grids over this Spacer way
    HStack{
        Spacer()
        Button{
            
        } label: {
            Text("Focused")
        }
        .font(.title3)
        .foregroundStyle(.shuttleGray)
        Spacer()
        Button{
            
        } label: {
            Text("Other")
        }
        .font(.title3)
        .foregroundStyle(.shuttleGray)
        Spacer()
    }
    HStack(spacing: 0){
        VStack(spacing:0){
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 2)
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 2)
        }
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 2)
    }
}


What is the exact question? What is your current vs. wanted outcome?

I'm unable to get the two focused & other buttons to appear as part of the navbar, the picture I included is my desired outcome but the buttons are just in their own stack in the view and not in the toolbar. i want to make them part of the toolbar so when scrolling down the search, all the toolbar buttons and the focused & other buttons are also part of the navbar

Does this answer your question? Add accessory view below navigation bar title in SwiftUI
